# HTML input & button to pass to function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

this is my first question on StackOverflow and my first time working with Chrome Extensions.

I am trying to get user input from an html popup and use jquery to pass that input to a javascript function. The openNewPopup function works here, and the removeATab function works only if I hard code a specific tab index within the function (not passing in the index).

My background.js

```
function openNewPopup() {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        index: 0,
        url: "http://google.com"
    }, function(tab) {
        console.log(tab);
    });
}
function removeATab(removeTab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        lastTabId = tabs[removeTab].id;
        chrome.tabs.remove(lastTabId);
    });
}
```

My popup_script.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    document.querySelector('#newTabButton').addEventListener('click', 
function() {
        backgroundPage.openNewPopup();
    });
    document.querySelector('#btnRemove').addEventListener('click', 
function() {
        var indexRemove = document.querySelector('#tabRemove');
        backgroundPage.removeATab(indexRemove);
    });
});
```

And my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Work with tabs</title>
        <script src="popup_script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>"Open new tab"</h3>
        <button id="newTabButton">Make a new tab!</button>   
        <div class="remove">
            Remove tab:<br>
            <input type="number" name="tabRemove" id="tabRemove">
            <br>
            <input type="button" id="btnRemove" value="Remove">
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ask the user to input the index of the tab they would like to close. I am using the chrome.tabs.remove method (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove). I can use the index to get the id of that tab. I need the tabID to use the chrome.tabs.remove function.

Comment: indexRemove is a DOM element. To get the value use `.value` property e.g. `backgroundPage.removeATab(Number(indexRemove.value));` BTW you don't need a background page for this.